# Create a view like contact info in ios4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to create a view like contacts info in new ios4. 
I've been looking for a document, source code(this is better) or something else but I wasn't lucky.
Please if somebody can help me I will be very very happy, I need to show a picture, some fields like textbox and description field.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` for your first table section, and point it to a `UIView` you've designed in IB.  Take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2009/03/01/transparent-table-header-uitableview/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the Address Book APIs? Here is a link to the Apple Developer site that should get you started:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

It goes over both how to integrate with the Address Book database, and how to just use an Address Book-like view for listing contact information.

Controllers: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not interesting in address book API, only in the view. I exactly I want to keep information from a car, so I'll put data from coredata like picture,model, name, date, description...
The problem is that I don't understand how can I make sections tableview and picture. Because I think that in contact view, the use a header view with picture and label and for data they use a normal table view with sections. But the backgroung color is the same...

Comment: Sorry for being misleading - the Address Book API allows you to create views like you want without actually being tied into Address Book. You can do whatever you wish with them. All of those tableviews and things come "for free" with the controllers the API provides. See the second link in my updated answer for details about the specific controllers in the API.